# PowerShell issue when using string variable from web.config in concatenation

Tags: powershell, string-concatenation, smo, powershell-4.0

I have this issue with a string ($dataBaseName variable) I'm pulling from a web.config file via a function.

When I [Write-Host](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Write-Host) it displays the value, and when I use GetType() it shows that it is a System.String, but it will not pull the value when concatenating with another variable. Eventually, I want to use it as a parameter to call from the module I'm writing.

Here is the code I use to get the $dataBaseName variable I'm having trouble with.

```
# Get WebConfig Detail
$configPath = Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432NodeItem\Key\Settings' `
| Select @{Name="Path";Expression={$_.installPath + "\Item\Web.config" }} `
-ExpandProperty Path
$config = [xml](Get-Content $configPath)

function Get-WebConfigKey($key) {
    $config.SelectSingleNode("//appSettings/add[@key='$key']").Value
}

# Set Database Variable
$databaseName = Get-WebConfigKey "databaseName"
```

Later I try to reference it by combining it with the computer variable using many different ways to concatenate it using (with (), string.format, etc.), but it will only display "ComputerName\" for the value of the $instance variable.

```
$computer = Get-Content env:computername
$instance = $computer + "\" + $databaseName
```

If I hard-code the database name it works fine.

```
$instance = $computer + "\" + "exampleDatabase"
```

I'm using the information to an SQL query as below. I'm actually going to use a secure string for the password later, but this is for reference.

```
$computer = Get-Content env:computername
$instance = $computer + "\" + $databaseName
$server = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $instance
$server.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure=$false
$server.ConnectionContext.set_Login("sa")
$server.ConnectionContext.set_Password("examplePassword")
$db = $server.Databases.Item("Maduro")
[String] $sql = "SELECT SomeRow FROM SomeTalbe;"
$result = $db.ExecuteWithResults($sql)
$table = $result.Tables[0]
foreach ($row in $table) {
    $someVarible = $row.SomeRow
}
```

Web.config excerpt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <!--NEXT GEN EF DB INFO-->
        <add key="providerName" value="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add key="serverName" value="LOCALHOST\Instance" />
        <add key="databaseName" value="database" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Not sure if the typo is in your question or in your actual code, but the variable name in `$datbaseName = Get-WebConfigKey "databaseName"` is one `a` short (`dat` instead of `data`).

Comment: Nice catch. That was a typo.

Comment: Can you provide sample XML?

Comment: Took an excerpt from the XML and added to the question. There are bunch of other nodes, but they all fall under configuration. When I use C#, I use System.Configuration.Configuration. I see with PowerShell, I can use it as well as [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Configuration") - I may give that a go.

Comment: `Get-WebConfigKey` returned the correct value when I tested it with your sample config. Does the real config perhaps contain another record with an empty database name? What do you get when you run `$config.SelectNodes("//appSettings/add[@key='$key']") | % { "_$($_.Value)_" }`?

Comment: Thanks, when I ran your code I got _dataBaseName_ then I removed the _ and it pulled the the right name for the database and I was able to connect the instance. I never would have thought to loop through the object to get the string.